# Move (or copy) regex match from line to the beginning of same line

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

Is there a way with sed or awk (or something else I'm not aware of) to move or copy a RegEx match from where it appears on the line to the beginning of that same line? I'm comfortable with the RegEx ( I'm using `/2021-06-26T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{3}Z/` as I'm specifically matching things on 2021-06-26), just not sure of a clever way to prepend the RegEx match to the line it's found on.

For instance given this:

```
hello 2021-06-26T20:45:20.111Z
hello 2021-06-26T20:45:20.111Z hi
hi 2021-06-26T20:35:20.111Z yes
hola yes yes 2021-06-27T20:45:20.111Z
hello 2021-06-26T22:45:20.111Z
hey 2021-06-26T23:45:20.111Z
yo 2021-06-26T20:45:20.111Z no
salut 2021-06-26T20:45:20.111Z random words here
bonjour 2021-06-26T20:45:20.111Z
```

Is there a way to copy these timestamps to the beginning of each line? e.g.

```
2021-06-26T20:45:20.111Z hello 2021-06-26T20:45:20.111Z
2021-06-26T20:45:20.111Z hello 2021-06-26T20:45:20.111Z hi
2021-06-26T20:35:20.111Z hi 2021-06-26T20:35:20.111Z yes
2021-06-27T20:45:20.111Z hola yes yes 2021-06-27T20:45:20.111Z
2021-06-26T22:45:20.111Z hello 2021-06-26T22:45:20.111Z
2021-06-26T23:45:20.111Z hey 2021-06-26T23:45:20.111Z
2021-06-26T20:45:20.111Z yo 2021-06-26T20:45:20.111Z no
2021-06-26T20:45:20.111Z salut 2021-06-26T20:45:20.111Z random words here
2021-06-26T20:45:20.111Z bonjour 2021-06-26T20:45:20.111Z
```

EDIT:
Googling led me to believe the `&` represented a sed match. Answers since have taught me about `\#` to match numbered groups with `()`

Things I tried that failed:

```
sed -E '/[2021-06-26T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{3}Z/' ~/sedtest
sed '/2021-06-26T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{3}Z/' ~/sedtest
sed -E '/2021-06-26T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{3}Z/' ~/sedtest
sed -E -n '/2021-06-26T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{3}Z/' ~/sedtest
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sed` can do this using groups `()` and references `\1`:

```
sed -E 's/(.*)(2021-06-26T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{3}Z)/\2 \1\2/'
```

Comment: Ah that is so simple. So if I'm understanding right the replace at the end ( `\2 \1\2/` ) Takes group 2 (the date regex) and adds it to the beginning of groups 1 and 2 with a space. This is perfect. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

If you're happy with your current regex, and you don't need to match > 1 occurrence of it, then you just need `.*` + a single subexpression:

```
sed -E 's/.*(2021-06-26T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{3}Z)/\1 &/' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Your regex seems correct only for date `2021-06-26`.

To make it match all dates following regex work for you:

```sh
sed -E 's/^(.*([0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{2}){2}T([0-9]{2}:){2}[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{3}Z))/\2 \1/' file

2021-06-26T20:45:20.111Z hello 2021-06-26T20:45:20.111Z
2021-06-26T20:45:20.111Z hello 2021-06-26T20:45:20.111Z hi
2021-06-26T20:35:20.111Z hi 2021-06-26T20:35:20.111Z yes
2021-06-27T20:45:20.111Z hola yes yes 2021-06-27T20:45:20.111Z
2021-06-26T22:45:20.111Z hello 2021-06-26T22:45:20.111Z
2021-06-26T23:45:20.111Z hey 2021-06-26T23:45:20.111Z
2021-06-26T20:45:20.111Z yo 2021-06-26T20:45:20.111Z no
2021-06-26T20:45:20.111Z salut 2021-06-26T20:45:20.111Z random words here
2021-06-26T20:45:20.111Z bonjour 2021-06-26T20:45:20.111Z
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5rNHFT/1)

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`'s `match` function one could try following code too.

```
awk '
match($0,/[0-9]+(-[0-9]+){2}T[0-9]+(:[0-9]+){2}\.[0-9]+Z/){
  $0=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) OFS $0
}
1
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, using `match` function of `awk` to match regex `[0-9]+(-[0-9]+){2}T[0-9]+(:[0-9]+){2}\.[0-9]+Z` which basically matches date and time as per shown samples. Then re-assigning values of matched part along with current line's value, then printing the lines(edited/non-edited ones).